# How to convert decimal to integer in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

for example I have ${var1}= 0.0 how can I convert ${var1}= 0 ?

What is the best way to do it ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Reference: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Convert%20To%20Integer

Use below line of code to convert to integer

```
${decimal}=    Set Variable    ${0.0}
${result} =    Convert To Integer    ${decimal}
```

Or

```
${result} =    Evaluate    int(${decimal})
```